# Unable to Join two keys to one Primary key with left join

Tags: join, alias

```
SELECT teams.teamname AS Home, 
       teams.teamname AS Away 
FROM   game 
       LEFT JOIN teams 
              ON game.awayteam = teams.teamid 
       LEFT JOIN teams AS T 
              ON game.hometeam = T.teamid
```

My Tables are as Follows

```
Game                                     
-GameId(Pk,int),
-HomeTeamId (fk,int),   
-AwayTeamId(fk,int)                     

Teams
-TeamId(Pk,int),
-TeamName(Varchar)
```

I am trying to view both the home team and away team name in a query.When I join the tables my expected results are the Home Team Name and Away Team Name, however in both tables only the Home Team name is listed.

```
Home Team|Spikes

Away Team|Spikes
```

when should be

```
Home Team|Spikes

Away Team|Raptors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give *both* joins an alias. You're selecting the result of the first join twice.

e.g.

```sql
SELECT
  GameId,
  home.TeamName AS Home,
  away.TeamName AS Away
FROM Game
  LEFT JOIN Teams AS away ON AwayTeamId = away.TeamId
  LEFT JOIN Teams AS home ON HomeTeamId = home.TeamId;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What you call 'alias' (verb) is actually a range variable (noun). The term 'alias' is misleading for the very reason you demonstrate here: "You need to give both joins an alias" -- a range variable represents a **row**, not a join (or a table).

Answer (score 0):

If you push renaming columns to the table expressions in the joins you can use `NATURAL JOIN` and avoid using range variables entirely. Also, I'm not convinced you actually need outer joins:

```
SELECT Home, Away
  FROM game
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT teamid AS hometeam
              teamname AS home
         FROM teams ) Home
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT teamid AS awayteam
              teamname AS Away
         FROM teams ) away;
```